# Ploblem in installing php5-curl

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, apt-get

I am trying to install curl module of php by following command on my Ubuntu machine-

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

But it is not getting installed and I am getting following error messages on console. Could you assist me and explain what is happening here. Why are those urls Forbidden?

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
root@XXXXXXXX:/etc/apt# apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql
Suggested packages:
  php-pear php5-suhosin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-curl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql
4 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,522kB of archives.
After this operation, 127kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main php5-cli i386 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main php5-mysql i386 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main libapache2-mod-php5 i386 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main php5-common i386 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main php5-curl i386 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10
  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-cli_5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-mysql_5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/libapache2-mod-php5_5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-common_5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-curl_5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: This belongs to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). Go and find solutions there, and try to read [FAQ].

Comment: looks like that mirror has got some problems, try to change apt-get repositories

Comment: or http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: since the urls suggest you're running ubuntu 10.10 (maveric m[something]): that's a non-LTS distro: it was supported until somewhere mid-way 2012. Best upgrade your distro, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my distro from ubuntu 10.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

If so, try the following sequence:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```